# .dll file not accessible

Tags: c#, .net, file, dll, reference

I am trying to add a dll to my project.
When I do "add reference" and try to add it, it tells me :

> "A reference to ... could not be added. please make sure that the file
>   in accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component".

BTW, I am trying to add g729.dll

**How can I add the dll?**

Comment: On what platform are you building the project ?

Comment: *Is* it a valid .NET assembly or COM component?

Comment: its the normal Visual Studio 2010 of Microsoft..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resolve "Please make sure that the file is accessible and that it is a valid assembly or COM component"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080447/how-do-i-resolve-please-make-sure-that-the-file-is-accessible-and-that-it-is-a)

Answer (score 7):

You must `register` your dll in register base before `add reference`

You can use `Regsvr32 tool`

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms859484.aspx

Comment: In my case I changed the dll installation folder and lost references at visual studio. Got the file back where it was before and things works again. Thanks for your help @AghilasYakoub

Comment: Aghilas, fyi - the link you provided no longer works!

Answer (score 3):

Register your dll by providing the proper path s below:-

Open the command prompt of your visual studio and register your dll

c:\Windows\System 32> regsvr32 yourdll.dll

Answer (score 0):

If you know assembly name and version like below you can un load project and open csproj in edit mode. Then find references and add you dll reference

Example

```
    <Reference Include="ReferenceDllAssemblyName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5a159fbc978150a3, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\TempPath\ReferenceDllAssemblyName.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```