# Compress and Extract with SevenZipSharp

Tags: c#, 7zip

I'm trying to compress and extract files with SevenZipSharp, but I'm getting following error:

> Can not load 7-zip library or internal COM error! Message: failed to load library.

My code:

```
string extractFrom = @"C:\Test\Test.7z";
string extractTo = @"C:\Test2";

string compressFrom = @"C:\Test2";
string compressTo = @"C:\Test\Test2.7z";

SevenZipBase.SetLibraryPath(@"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.dll");

SevenZipCompressor compressor = new SevenZipCompressor();
compressor.CompressionMode = CompressionMode.Create;
compressor.TempFolderPath = Path.GetTempPath();
compressor.ArchiveFormat = OutArchiveFormat.SevenZip;
compressor.CompressDirectory(compressFrom, compressTo);//Error

SevenZipExtractor extractor = new SevenZipExtractor(extractFrom);
extractor.ExtractArchive(extractTo);//Error
```

The error is at:

```
compressor.CompressDirectory(compressFrom, compressTo);
```

and at:

```
extractor.ExtractArchive(extractTo);
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Most obvious answer: the dll is not at the given path.

But I assume you've tried that, but if you mix 32 bit and 64 bit applications this is also a known issue. So if your application is running 32 bits and the 7zip is installed as x64 this error will be thrown.

Also see this: [A reference to .dll could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29424657/a-reference-to-dll-could-not-be-added-please-make-sure-that-the-file-is-access)

Comment: I tryed with 32-Bit and 64-Bit and both are not working.

Comment: SevenZipSharp is basically just a wrapper for the COM object - since that error is being thrown I suggest you read into the answer (and links) from the referenced SO question

Comment: I just found my mistake: I use .Net 4.5.2 but SevenZipSharp is just compatible up to .Net 4.0.

Comment: @daniel59: I use SevenZipSharp, too, but my project uses .Net 4.5.2, so it may have had some other reason in your case.