# How to solve TlbImp : error TI0000

Tags: c#, dll, ghostscript, tlbimp

I am trying to add a reference to a 3rd party DLL. but was having same problem as [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080447/i-want-a-solution-for-this-please-make-sure-that-the-file-is-accessible-and-th).

So Now I am trying to validate the DLL using TlbImp.exe but this approach gives me New error;

> TlbImp : error TI0000 : The input file 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\gsdll32.dll' is not a valid
>   type library

I tried following links but nobody has given any solution on this.

[Link 1](http://www.dotnetask.com/44909_3473646/)
[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456758/a-reference-to-the-dll-could-not-be-added) (Question is asked in correct answer's comment)

Comment: You'll need to stop trying, Ghostscript is not implemented as a COM server so therefore does not have a type library.  Use an existing .NET wrapper for it, [like this one](https://github.com/jhabjan/Ghostscript.NET).

Comment: Thanks. I used nuget from the link you suggested. :)