# Why my Release only works on my machine?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I am on Windows 64bit working with Visual Studio 2015. I have this WPF project with its C++ backend and it uses several additional packages such as OpenCV, EmguCV and DevExpress.

Now if I run as `Release`, it compiles fine. Also if I go to the current directory via explorer and navigate to `bin -> Release` then execute the `.exe` file, it also runs fine.

**Problem:** The project does not work on any other machine: If I copy the whole *Release* folder and paste it onto another machine, and try to execute, it pops a "*Could not load file or assembly*" error. See [**Error Here**](https://s15.postimg.org/wwy05pzy3/EZ3_D_error.png) and the full error  below.

**Insights:** Those target machines used to be able to execute a Release just fine and the same way (Copy/Paste or Installer). The project targets `.Net framework 4.5` and needs the 2013 + 2015 redistributable files. Everything is installed on the target machine. Also the Dlls that the error is mad about, exist physically in the Release folder. And when I build an installer (using `Inno Setup`) I see all the needed and existing Dlls being included (OpenCv stuff and DevExpress).

There are like 10 OpenCv Dlls that are not shown within "*Solution Explorer -> References*" but physically exist in the Release Folder (we pasted them their). Now, if I remove these files from MY Release Folder, I get the exact same error. On the other hand, if I paste them in THEIR Release Folder, the error persists.

The "*Solution Explorer -> References -> Properties -> Local Copy*" of all the files are set to true. I currently build as x86, because if I build as x64 I get this error:

> Error NuGet Error: Unable to find version '2.4.8' of package 'OpenCV.overlay-x64_v120_Release'. C:\Users\bla\Desktop\bla\packages\OpenCV.2.4.8\build\native\OpenCV.targets

What could be the issue?

**Complete Error:**

> Fatal @ 9/9/2016 9:18:19 AM - CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException
>   v2.0.1.0 - Exception Info: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException:
>   The invocation of the constructor on type 'bla.MainWindow' that
>   matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception. --->
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'bla.bla.bla.dll' or one of its dependencies. The
>   specified module could not be found.
>
> at bla.MainWindow..ctor()
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader,
>   IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean
>   skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings
>   settings, Uri baseUri)
>
> at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader
>   xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject,
>   XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
>
> at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream,
>   ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
>
> at System.Windows.Application.LoadBamlStreamWithSyncInfo(Stream
>   stream, ParserContext pc)
>
> at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Uri resourceLocator,
>   Boolean bSkipJournaledProperties)
>
> at System.Windows.Application.DoStartup()
>
> at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1_0(Object unused)
>
> at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
>
> at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object
>   source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate
>   catchHandler)
>
> at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
>
> at
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object
>   state)
>
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>
> at
>   MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>
> at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
>
> at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
>
> at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32
>   msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
>
> at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam,
>   IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
>
> at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
>
> at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object
>   source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate
>   catchHandler)
>
> at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority
>   priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32
>   numArgs)
>
> at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg,
>   IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
>
> at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
>
> at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame
>   frame)
>
> at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame
>   frame)
>
> at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
>
> at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
>
> at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
>
> at bla.App.Main()

Comment: Try turning on the Fusion log -- http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx

Comment: Did you turn on the Fusion log?

Comment: @j.h I just started. Sorry for being late. I should execute fusion on the target machine and where the error is correct? Would you mind going to a chat room?

Comment: @FirstStep - Yes, the machine having the issue. I don't mind going to a chat room.

Answer (score 1):

I found this link that may help you

[I want a solution for this : Please make sure that the file is accessible and that it is a valid assembly or COM component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080447/i-want-a-solution-for-this-please-make-sure-that-the-file-is-accessible-and-th)

Marked answer is:

the file is a native DLL which means you can't add it to a .NET project via Add Reference... you can use it via DllImport (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.aspx)

Comment: Mohammed I still think it is something related to build, references, something need to be checked as true. It is how I used to do it since ever, for each release: I just build and copy paste the folder. I don't know what got messed recently so it is not working on the target machine anymore.. I don't want to take the hard coding road. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Right click references in the project then re-add the assemplies for the OpenCV again, then refresh and re-build the solution. Also make sure that the  project targets .Net framework 4.5 indeed, because sometimes the same errors appear if it targets .net client framework.

Comment: I couldn't. It pops error "Can't Add Components: https://s18.postimg.org/lqqqlk0kp/Capture1.png

Comment: try to remove them then re-add these refernces

Comment: Hasoun, they were not added in the first place. So I can't remove them and then re add them. I just copy paste them..