# Adding a custom library to Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I found out in GitHub this awesome library i need and i do not know how to install it into VisualStudio2015.

https://github.com/TinkerWorX/AccidentalNoiseLibrary

I have tried to answer my problem by searching for similar questions but those are for .dll and simple extensions. When it comes to something as big as that. How you actually do it?

I use Visual Studio 2015 and my goal is to use that library on Unity for a project of mine.

Thanks

Edit: Posting the error i get when i try to reference a class from another project.

[image]

I also tried to add that library into Unity project but still can not access.

Comment: Add reference to the project ?

Comment: It does not let me as there is not any .dll or compatible thing. All it has is classes and it does not let me reference them that way. I click of references, the Add Reference then (as there is no compatible thing) i change filter and chose the class i want. But nothing.

Comment: You need to compile it do get .dll and then add reference to the project.

Comment: Compile that library i downloaded, right?

Comment: That looks like a csproj - so download into a folder and reference the project in your solution. What could go wrong there :)

Comment: I am trying to reference it. Does not let me. Gives me an error.

Comment: Why do not you post that error ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want a solution for this : Please make sure that the file is accessible and that it is a valid assembly or COM component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080447/i-want-a-solution-for-this-please-make-sure-that-the-file-is-accessible-and-th)

Comment: not a duplicate. I dont need a .dll. I just need access to ImplicitFractal class.

Comment: So you downloaded the code into a new folder under your solution, then did add existing project, then did a project reference from your main project to the new project?

Comment: Yes, i tried everything but without success so far.

Comment: is there some kind of tool to make it .dll and install it into Visual Studio?

Comment: Well, it is the source code for a project. So you could create a new solution (library type) then add this code as a project, compile and take the dll out of the bin folder. Better yet, do as I just described - open your Unity solution and add the source code as a new project and do a project reference where needed. You can't just download and try to link the csproj source code file.

Comment: i don't know how to do that. I am not used to such things.

Comment: Yyyeeeees! Done it! Now go and ask your boss fora  raise @SteveGreene

Comment: So did you end up building a DLL or doing a project reference? The project reference would allow you to modify the code to meet your needs.

Comment: I added and answer. Feel free to edit any mistakes i made pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to solve this problem for a C# in Visual Studio.

How do i transform from SourceCode to a .dll extension to use in other projects?

1. Download your SourceCode
2. Open up Visual Studio
3. Go to **File** -> **New** -> **Project**
4. Choose **Class Library**
5. Delete the Class that comes by default
6. Open up your **SourceCode** and **Drag it into the Project**

   **NOTE:** If there are folders, manually open and drag their contents. I found 
        out that only by dragging it does load its content (what is inside the folder) so manually transfer it
7. **Build It!**
8. Then go to **File** -> **Add Source Control**
9. Then Open up the project you where working on and **Reference** -> **Add 
   Reference**
10. **Browse** the .dll and you are done.

Thanks for the help!