# System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'Teigha.Core.GlobalsPINVOKE' threw an exception.'

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I'm developing a C# desktop application that uses C++ dll's. I'm facing an issue that I cant resolve:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'Teigha.Core.GlobalsPINVOKE' 
threw an exception.'
1 of 2 Inner Exceptions:
TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'SWIGExceptionHelper' threw an 
exception.
2 of 2 Inner Exceptions:
DllNotFoundException: Unable to load dll 'TD_SwigCore_22.7_16.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E).
```

1. My first try was to add the dll by going to project reference -> add reference but then I go a error message:

   `A reference to C:\blablabla\TD_SwigCore_22.7_16.dll could not be added. Please make sure that  the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.`
2. Second try was to try it with DllImport as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0
   I get a compiler error:

   `C50592: Attribute #dllImport' is not valid on this declaration type. it is only valid on 'method' declarations.`
3. Third try was to use regsvr32 as explained as one of the possible solutions on: [How do I resolve "Please make sure that the file is accessible and that it is a valid assembly or COM component"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080447/how-do-i-resolve-please-make-sure-that-the-file-is-accessible-and-that-it-is-a)

   `regsvr32 "C:\blablabla\TD_SwigCore_22.7_16.dll"`

   And got the error message:

   `the module "C:\blablabla\TD_SwigCore_22.7_16.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found. Make sure that "C:\blablabla\TD_SwigCore_22.7_16.dll" is a valid DLL or OCX file and then try again`
4. My fourth and last try was to find out what all dependencies of my 'TD_SwigCore_22.7_16.dll' are, and I have done it like this:

   `dumpbin /DEPENDENTS "C:\blablabla\TD_SwigCore_22.7_16.dll"`

   and I have gotten a list with all dependencies, and then I have added all those dll's in the folder bin\x64\Debug as explained in one of the stack overflow solutions, but I still got the same error.

By now I feel like I have tried all solutions that I can find on the internet, but nothing works.
It is important to know that my program works perfectly fine on release mode, only not on debug mode.

Target framework is: .NET Framework 4.8

And help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you dumpbin /exports "C:\blablabla\TD_SwigCore_22.7_16.dll" and share ? or even better use http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: Welcome. You can also use the [fusion log viewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer) to see the DLLs that have been loaded & the ones that cannot be found (and even where the CLR tried to look for them).

Comment: @Orenico when I do it in exports the list is longer than 25k so I can not share it, and when I suse dependecywalker and open my .exe file I can not profile it. 
I've tried what is written here: https://www-archive.mozilla.org/quality/help/dependency-walker.html

Comment: @imsmn I am not sure that will help Fuslogvw utility is mainly used to resolve bindings issues with managed assemblies and David is facing an issue with unmanaged one c++ compiled and linked one if I am getting his question right

Comment: @David I guess that the c++ dll isn't a com component so it is useless to try and regsvr this dll and the error you get on 3) make sense as there is no Dllregister function to that matter. I can try and further assist if you can paste the wrapper you tried with dllimport attribute

Comment: @Orenico I am not sure if I understand right what should I paste?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was in the project settings under debug more the wrong folder was chosen. I chose the folder (same as for release) with all the dll's and it worked.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem. Please could you provide further details to the solution. Is it the Working directory that must be set?

Comment: Figured it out. You don;t need to set a working folder, just have all the dll's in the correct folder and don't fool yourself that you have already done that.