# Cannot create valid dll by using Visual C++ 2012

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, dllexport

I tried to create a dll with Visual C++ 2012 by following [this walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms235636.aspx), but I failed. When I tried to import built dll in a different project as a reference, I got this error: `A reference to '***.dll' could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.`

I don't understand what my mistake is in code and why I get this error. Here is my header and cpp file:

### DLLEXPORT.H

```
__declspec(dllexport) bool setMute();
__declspec(dllexport) bool setActive();
```

### DLLEXPORT.CPP

```
#include "DLLEXPORT.H"
bool setMute(){
    //some stuff
}
bool setActive(){
    //some stuff
}
```

Moreover, I also tried to solve the problem by this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456758/a-reference-to-the-dll-could-not-be-added), but I got this error: `TlbImp : error TI1002 : The input file '****.dll' is not a valid type library.`

Comment: add also this names into file with exported definitions

Comment: Your DLL is not a .NET assembly and not a COM server so adding it as a reference cannot work.  You will need to use [DllImport] to use it.

Comment: Dll created by such way should be added to a client C/C++ project using linker additional dependencies, and not as .NET or COM reference. You need to add .lib file to the linker list.

Comment: Or you can add DLL project to the same solution and then add reference to DLL project from your target project.

Comment: Sounds to me like a more accurate title would be something like: "How do I use a DLL from managed code?"

Comment: Even though you are making and using a DLL, when doing the link you give the linker the .LIB file.  Also the using code needs to use __declspec(dllimport) for your symbols.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. As you said, I have to use [DllImport].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different kinds of DLLs (and EXEs) in Microsoft world: native DLLs, prodoced by native C++ (or C) and assemblies, containing .NET executable stuff. The walkthrough you have read will give you a native DLL, while the referencing you try to do is meant only for .NET assemblies (and COM components).

So you either have to build a .NET DLL (which would be C++/CLI and not native C++), or link your native DLL to a native app (or importing it) instead of referencing it in a .NET project.