# C# Unable to add reference basic.dll

Tags: c#, .net, dll, reference, rfid

Hi guys im just new in C# i came from a PHP background. I'm working on a RFID project which has RRU1861CSharp.dll which is dependent to basic.dll. I am able to add reference RRU1861CSharp.dll but when i'm trying to add reference basic.dll it says:

"basic.dll could not be added please make sure that the file is accessible, and that is a valid assembly or COM component".

I cant post picture sorry i don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Well where is `basic.dll`? Do you have it? Do you know if you need to register it in the GAC? (Where did you get RRU1861CSharp.dll?)

Comment: it's at the same folder as RRU1861CSharp.dll. i doubt it's about permission sir since i am able to add reference RRU1861CSharp.dll
sir pardon for my ignorance. what is GAC?

Comment: So you tried adding the reference by just browsing to the DLL in Explorer? Are you able to open it in any other tool? Have you *checked* the permissions?

Comment: yes sir i only tried it via explorer. it has full permission sir.

Comment: Are you sure `basic.dll` is a valid .NET assembly?

Comment: sir I think i have found the right thread [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456758/a-reference-to-the-dll-could-not-be-added#_=_ ) but i somehow cannot understand. can you please enlighten me to #5 solution in the said thread please.

Comment: how should i know sir? i think it is sir since it comes with the SDK provided by the company.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add the dependencies of RRU1861CSharp.dll to the project. It sounds like it's not a .NET assembly which is why you can't; however, you do have to ensure that it is installed on the final client/server where your app will run, along with all the other dependencies of RRU1861CSharp.dll.

It also has to be accessible on you dev machine to run the app from VS.

However, it is not a reference: References are only the things your app needs directly.

Comment: sir i have the same problem as this one [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456758/a-reference-to-the-dll-could-not-be-added#_=_) he solve his own problem however i dont understand it completely can you please enlighten me sir.