# Adding Libspotify SDK to a .NET solution

Tags: c#, libspotify

I'm trying to add the [`Libspotify SDK`](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/libspotify/) to a test solution. However, I got the following error:

[image]

Now, I tried following the first answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456758/a-reference-to-the-dll-could-not-be-added) question. However, all I got was:

[image]

The package of the library is structured in the following way:

[image]

Additionaly, my project is targeted to `.NET Framework 4.0`

And the configuration is done as follows:

[image]

What can I do to add this library?

**EDIT:**

Also, I found [this](https://libspotifydotnet.codeplex.com/discussions/454545) link where someone explains that it need to be copied manually into the project output directory. I tried putting the `.dll` there, but I guess I have to modify something else to make it work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The libspotify.dll you are trying to access is a Win32 C library, not a C# (.NET) assembly. As such, you can only use it through [interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173185.aspx).

You don't have to do this yourself (judging by your question I'm assuming you have no previous experience with the techniques involved), you can use a ready-made solution like [libspotify.NET](https://libspotifydotnet.codeplex.com/).