# COM reference not available after successful regsvr32

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, com

I'm stuck on a COM DLL registing successfully, but not showing up as COM reference in my Visual Studio.

I run regsvr32 (as admin) and get a "successfully registered" message. Also, I ran ILDASM against the DLL to make sure it's a COM DLL and not a .NET DLL. Also, I have legacy code using the DLL via COM, so I guess it's safe to assume the DLL is indeed a valid COM DLL.

However, after registering, the reference doesn't show up in Visual Studio ("Add reference"). Does anyone have any pointer where I could look to find out what's wrong?

Comment: There's no particular reason why this *should* work, use the owner's usage instructions.  Using the Browse button and selecting the DLL could be your next guess.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I needed to add the VB6 runtime (msvbvm60.dll). After that, the registration was successful and I found the COM library in VS 2010. (credits to [A reference to the dll could not be added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456758/a-reference-to-the-dll-could-not-be-added))