# How to fix "A reference to MSO.dll could not be added"?

Tags: c#, dll, ms-office, onenote

Env:64-bit Win10 + 64-bit VS 2015
I am trying to develop an onenote add-in.
When I add a reference to MSO.dll, an alert pops-up saying

> "A reference to 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft
>   Shared\OFFICE15\MSO.DLL' could not be added. Please make sure that the
>   file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component"

I've tried [A reference to the dll could not be added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456758/a-reference-to-the-dll-could-not-be-added)
1. using TlbImp.exe and get following error:

> TlbImp : warning TI0000 : Primary interop assembly 'Office,
>   Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71E9BCE111E9429C' is
>   already registered for type library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common
>   Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE15\MSO.DLL'. TlbImp : error TI0000 :
>   System.IO.IOException - Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

2. using dependency walker and found that quite a lot of dll files like these can not be found:

> API-MS-WIN-CORE-ATOMS-L1-1-0.DLL
>   EXT-MS-MF-PAL-L2-1-0.DLL

3. In excel using VBE, MSO.dll can be referenced.

Quite confused about this error, please share how to fix this problem.
Thanks for any hints/replies

Comment: Why do you need to add the MSO reference manually?

Comment: Well, I can NOT find microsoft office 15.0 object library in the COM tab in the reference list. I've tried to re-install MS office. But it still doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the issue is caused, because 32 bit COM components cannot be loaded into 64 bit processes. Change your Project to x86 and it might work!?