# dll reference Error in c# windows form App project

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dll, dllimport

I am trying to add a dll into my windows form application type project. However, when I am adding the dll to reference folder it is throwing an error and restricting me to add the same. Enclosed is a screenshot. Can anyone please let me know, under which condition we get this error and how to fix it?

Note: I am not aware, the dll has been produced using what tool or version/type of it. 
[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hici9.png)

The message is:

> A reference to C:\xyz.dll. dll could not be added, Please make sure
>   that the file is accessible and that it is a valid assembly or COM
>   component.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A reference to the dll could not be added](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456758/a-reference-to-the-dll-could-not-be-added)

Answer (score 0):

It's is exactly what you read and the message says.

Either thhis DLL doesn't contain any .NET code or class, or this DLL isn't a valid ActiveX DLL containing a typelib.

You can not add a DLL as a reference if it is not one of the above.

This is a [possible duplicate to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456758/a-reference-to-the-dll-could-not-be-added)