# DLL file not referenced after publishing WPF. But its working during debugging and building

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to deploying wpf in .net. I am building a form over a previous project. It contains 2 dll files for 32 bit and 64 bit machines. I can access the dll files when debugging. But when I deploy it, its not referenced at all. I tried to reference it by clcking add references i am getting the following error.

[image: image of error message]

can anyone help?

Comment: Without any further info, I suspect your dll might be built for a different .net framework version. At least that's when I usually get this error. The error is pretty common. You might want to look here for more ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456758/a-reference-to-the-dll-could-not-be-added

Comment: solved the issue. It was a post build command issue. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Please post a solution as an answer so people coming across this later can see how you solved it :)

Comment: set post-build event as `xcopy /d "$(ProjectDir)ReaderDLL\*.dll" "$(TargetDir)"` in project properties -> Build Events. i.e., copying the dlls to the target directory